# For loops in single statement

Tags: python

consider below example:

```
set_x = [1,1,1,1,1]
set_y = [2,2,2,2,2]
x += (item_x * item_y for item_x, item_y in set_x and set_y)
```

It shows an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'generator'
```

Please help how to resolve this

Comment: `product_lst = [x * y for x, y in zip(set_x, set_y)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to aggregate elements from multiple iterators:

```
[item_x * item_y for item_x, item_y in zip(set_x,set_y)]
# [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

So use:

```
x += (item_x * item_y for item_x, item_y in zip(set_x,set_y))
```

Comment: @prayaspagade remember to accept if this solved for you, thank you!

Comment: Yes, that had solved for the issue for me Thank you @yatu